# Javascript/jQuery prepend images

Tags: javascript, jquery, repeat

I'm a student, and new to JS and jQuery. I'm trying to make a little facebook-like project, because I can put a lot of different things in that. Right now the HTML is just static, but as soon as i have more knowledge, I plan to make it user-generated.

I have the different 'Facebook' posts. each post is an article, and the whole is in a section titled 'newsfeed', the articles have this syntax:

- `<H1>`, with the full name, given a class with their abbreviated name.
- `<p>`, with their 'status update'. after this i append an `<ul>` with javascript, containing `<li>`s with like, comment and share.

I then added some jQuery/JS code to add a profile picture

```
profilePics = function () {
    var name = $('article h1').attr('class');
    name = capitalizeFirstLetter(name);
    console.log(name);
    var path = '../media/profile/' + name + '_Square_0.png';
    console.log(path);
    $('article h1').prepend('<img src="' + path + '" alt="image of ' + name + '">')
};
```

When I run this, it shows the alt-text of the image, indicating it can't open the image. My problem exists out of two parts:

1. I triple-checked the path, so basically the only thing that could be wrong with it is that i don't go to the correct parent-directory. Do i start counting position from the JS file or the directory it's in?
2. I want to add a different picture for each (not determined how much) post. Right now it looks at the first post for the class, and then adds it to ALL posts

Comment: When dealing with web development, the console (`f12`) (chrome is my preference) is your go-to tool.. It will have debug info and error outputs for you to digest! The image missing will throw a `404` error and tell you where its TRYING to find the image.

Comment: 1. Try using full path to image file; 2. to select first `article` element try using `:eq()` http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/ , e.g.; `article:eq(0)`

Comment: Your path should be the same as if you were trying to bring up that image in your web browser. For example, if you can view the image at http://example.com/media/profile/foo_Square_0.png, then your path var should be `'/media/profile/foo_Square_0.png'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add different picture on any `<h1>` you have to loop over them. And your http image path must by absolute, not relative.

```
profilePics = function () {

    var imgPath = '/http-img-path/from/web-root/';

    $('article h1').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('class');
        $(this).prepend("<img src='"+imgPath + name + "_Square_0.png' alt='image of "+name+"'");

    });

};
```